# How can i get an element value from Payload XML in mule?

Tags: xml, mule, anypoint-studio

From this XML i want to get the id and set in a variable. 
Example : OrderID = 4258477000

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <order>
       <id type="integer">4258477000</id>
       <email>khaleed@mmtvbd.com</email>
       <closed-at type="dateTime" nil="true"/>
       <created-at type="dateTime">2016-10-24T21:41:51+06:00</created-at>
       <updated-at type="dateTime">2016-10-24T21:41:52+06:00</updated-at>
    <number type="integer">19</number>
    </order>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can Either use XPATH or dataweave to do so.

Xpath :-

`#[xpath3('/*:order/*:id',payload,"STIRNG")]`

OR Dataweave:-

```
<dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
    <dw:input-payload mimeType="application/xml"/>
    <dw:set-variable variableName="variableName"><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
payload.order.id]]>
    </dw:set-variable>
</dw:transform-message>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually i am getting XML data using message.inboundAttachments. Would you please help me how can i get the ID to a variable. I have tried your code. but not working.

Comment: #[xpath3('/*:order/*:id',payload,"STRING")] with the wildcard namespaces, payload and data type parms worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If the "id" field you are trying to extract is from an attachment then the issue you will have to solve first is retrieving the xml. The individual message.inboundAttachments element value will return you an javax.activation.DataHandler data type. You will have to convert this to either xml or string to make it workable.

One way to accomplish this would be to:

1. Create a customer transformer using the @InboundAttachments Annotation (https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/inboundattachments-annotation)
2. Convert the DataHandler Object to a String

   ```
   final InputStream in = dataHandler.getInputStream();
   byte[] byteArray=org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
   ```
3. Either extract the data and store it into a variable inside your transformer, or return the string/xml as your payload and use xpath or dataweave on your next component.

It's a little complicated, I know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<set-variable variableName="myvar" value="#[payload.order.id]" doc:name="Variable"/>
```